# употреблять/употребить and использовать/поиспользовать - what is difference(s) between these verbs?

Tags: перевод, значения, глаголы

For translators all of those verbs are the verb ***to use*** in English. Is it correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"**Использовать**" is the most universal word for "to use", and also for "to exploit" and "to utilize". It can be used for any kind of inanimate things, both material items and non-material things (like chances, capacities, technologies and so on). For example:

> В нашей работе мы используем новейшие технологии, современное оборудование и высококачественные материалы.
>
> In our work we use the newest technologies, modern equipment and high-quality materials.

But when "использовать" is used for people, it means that one treats the person like an inanimate thing, not a human. Of course, it sounds negative. For example:

> Я считал его другом, но он просто использовал меня для своей выгоды!
>
> I claimed that he was my friend, but he just exploited me to his own
>   benefit!

"**Поиспользовать**" sounds awkward and is used rarely. But when it is, as @Justin McGuire already noticed in his answer, it usually means the same as "использовать" about people. For inanimate things it is almost never used, just use "использовать" instead.

"**Употреблять/употребить**" have more narrow meaning than "использовать". It is **not** used for people, for non-material things (except for words and grammatical constructs) and for material things, which remain intact after usage, and can be used again later. The meaning of "употреблять" is closer to "to consume". It can be used for food, drinks, drugs and other things we take inside our body. It can also be used for different kinds of supplies, which transform or disappear after usage, for example:

> Эти доски давно без дела лежат, занимают много места. Надо бы их на что-то
>   употребить...
>
> These planks have been lying here for long time, occupying much space.
>   They should be used this or that way...

As mentioned in @Justin McGuire's answer, "употреблять/употребить" is also used for words and grammar categories. Examples:

> 1) Это матерное слово, не употребляй его в приличном обществе!
>
> This is a swear word, don't use it in polite company!
>
> 2) Какой падеж здесь употреблять - родительный или винительный?
>
> Which case should be used here - Genitive or Accusative?

"Использовать" can be used instead of "употреблять" in all these cases, *except for things you take inside and for words*. Grammatical categories and supplies allow both verbs.

**If you have doubts, which verb to use, it's better to use "использовать", because it is correct in most cases.**

Comment: спасибо вам большое! я понял все!

Answer (score 2):

"**употреблять/употребить**" is about a grammatical aspect. "**Употребить**" is a perfect aspect (meaning that it was a single action). E.g. Yesterday I used (*употребил*) that f-word (I mean I did it once). "**Употреблять**" is an imperfect . E.g. All my childhood I used (*употреблял*) only good words (meaning it was more than once, lots of single actions for some period of time).

"**Использовать**" a bit differs from "*употреблять*". "**Употреблять**" is usually used with "words" (meaning saying words) and with something that goes inside you (e.g. about food - *употреблять в пищу*). "**Использовать**" (btw, omonynic forms - both imperfect and perfect aspects depending on the context) is just "use".

And "**поиспользовать**" sounds a bit negative (very rarely about inanimate, usually about people), e.g. "Поиспользовал и бросил" - about a girl who was later dumped by a douche.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i still couldn't get it quite well:/

Comment: You don't mean an actual douche? :) It just sounds strange in the same sentence. "Поиспользовать" is redundant and sounds awkward, it's either "использовать" or "попользовать" (folksy).

Comment: I should say that on the contrary поиспользовать что-либо is almost always used with inanimate things. Its meaning is, 'to have used smth for a while but then cease to do so'. For example: *Мне как-то подарили Bluetooth-наушники, я их поиспользовал немного, да так и не приноровился. Теперь где-то валяются без дела.* An equivalent would be попользоваться чем-либо.

Comment: About "поиспользовать", the only clear thing is that this form is very rare, sounds awkward, and probably is even ungrammatical (though still understandable). That's why I think that it should be avoided. "Попользовать(-ся)" sounds much better and is really used to express "to use a little, for a short time".

Comment: @Lara, don't see why 'поиспользовать' would be ungrammatical. Somewhat clumsy, yes, but ungrammatical, certainly not. 'Попользовать' without '-ся', on the other hand, is wrong in your example. 'Пользовать' means 'to render services': *Новый доктор, присланный в деревню взамен уехавшего, успел попользовать Ивана Петровича всего два месяца, после чего тот скончался.* Nowadays 'пользовать' is often confused with 'пользоваться', and that's an error.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy, I started to think that "поиспользовать" is ungrammatical, because Google didn't find it in any dictionaries, and I can't remember a single occurence of this word in books or any "official" conversations. That's why I doubt if such word really exists in Russian language. And about "попользовать" you are right, thanks! It is used commonly in this meaning, but that usage is wrong.

Comment: @Lara I'm sure that "поиспользовал" is ungrammatical (and yes, I admit I made a mistake in my answer about this word and Andrey's definition fits much better). But sometimes Russians coin colloquial words to show nuances when there is no short equivalent. The prefix "по-" is often used with the meaning of doing something for a while (e.g. "побегать" - to jog for a while, "попрыгать" - to jump for a while, maybe to stretch legs, etc.) So the idea is that the word itself is ungrammatical but the opponent gets the right nuance 'cause they know as natives where such prefix/whatever can be used.

Comment: @Justin, I strongly disagree about 'поиспользовать' being ungrammatical. The 'по-' pattern of verb formation is productive in modern Russian. You can append 'по-' to virtually any imperfective verb, and that'll make sense.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy "попонимать" is grammatically correct too? :) Some words still sound unnatural with "по-" (e.g. "поумываться", "покупаться" formed from "купаться"). Btw, "ихний" also makes sense but is considered as ungrammatical

Comment: @JustinMcGuire, Certainly, all these instances are grammatically correct, and I can make sentences in which they make perfect sense. 'Ихний' is a completely different story because it doesn't follow a Russian productive pattern, it's just a Ukrainism.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy In this case we need to distinguish "grammatically correct" and "unnatural". And the latter is more relevant for language learners. Russian is not Esperanto, patterns work well not in all cases :)

Comment: @JustinMcGuire, I see no point in speaking of things being natural or unnatural. The easy thing to know is that 'по-' pattern is productive in modern Russian, and may be used quite consistently with imperfective verbs to turn them into perfective ones while conveying a certain idea, namely, the idea of an action which was performed for a while but then ceased to be. Of course, with some verbs, it may be quite difficult to find a situation in life where that idea of 'for-a-whileness' combines with them well, but when you find one, the pattern is there for you.

Answer (score 0):

These words are often interchangeable, but there are some established expressions in which one word is preferable to the other. They are also similar etymologically (cognate with *потребность* и *польза*, respectively).

*Поиспользовать* from the title of your question is redundant and awkward with both prefixes *по-* and *ис-*. The suffix *по-* instead of *ис-* here would mean the speaker is an oaf who had his way with someone. That's just the only context that comes to mind. Although one could use the other words in that context.

*Употреблять* somewhat implies consuming (e.g. food), and *использовать*, *пользоваться* implies using something without consuming it (e.g. a plate) . Also, *использовать* sounds more modern and is used (no pun intended) when talking about science and technology, for example.

Another difference is that there is a cognate reflexive verb *пользоваться* ("*я пользуюсь зубной щеткой*"), but no similar form with *употреблять*; the verb *употребляться* is only used in passive voice ("*зубные щетки не употребляются в пищу*").

Some established expressions with the word *употреблять*, as Justin McGuire pointed out, are *употреблять в пищу*, *употреблять выражения*.

A bad translation from English will usually be *использовать*.